# How to find the dependency where I should exclude the library?

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

I updated Maven from **3.0.5** to **3.5.3** version. I use **maven-site-plugin-3.7**.

After the updates I try to  execute command "mvn site site:deploy". I have the following error:

```
[ERROR] : org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: 
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader 
hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 
'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed. (Caused by 
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader 
hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 
'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed.) (Caused by     
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: 
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader 
hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 
'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed. (Caused by 
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader 
hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 
'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed.))
```

When I execute *dependency:tree* or *dependency:list* I have empty dependency list. When I execute *dependency:resolve-pugins* I have the following:

```
 --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:resolve-plugins (default-cli) @ ftpbc ---
[INFO] Plugin Resolved: maven-enforcer-plugin-1.0.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-artifact-2.0.9.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-plugin-api-2.0.9.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-project-2.0.9.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-core-2.0.9.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: plexus-utils-1.5.8.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: commons-lang-2.3.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: enforcer-api-1.0.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: enforcer-rules-1.0.jar
[INFO] Plugin Resolved: maven-site-plugin-3.7.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-reporting-exec-1.4.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-shared-utils-3.1.0.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-core-3.0.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-model-3.0.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-plugin-api-3.0.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-settings-3.0.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-settings-builder-3.0.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-archiver-3.1.1.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: sisu-inject-plexus-1.4.2.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: plexus-archiver-3.4.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-10.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: plexus-utils-3.0.24.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: doxia-sink-api-1.8.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: doxia-module-xhtml-1.8.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: doxia-module-apt-1.8.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: doxia-module-xdoc-1.8.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: doxia-module-fml-1.8.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: doxia-module-markdown-1.8.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: servlet-api-2.5.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: doxia-decoration-model-1.8.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: doxia-site-renderer-1.8.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: doxia-integration-tools-1.8.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: wagon-provider-api-1.0.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: jetty-6.1.25.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: jetty-util-6.1.25.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: commons-lang3-3.4.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: commons-io-2.5.jar
[INFO] Plugin Resolved: maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-plugin-api-2.0.6.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: plexus-utils-2.0.5.jar
[INFO] Plugin Resolved: maven-deploy-plugin-2.5.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-plugin-api-2.0.6.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-project-2.0.6.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-model-2.0.6.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-artifact-2.0.6.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: plexus-utils-1.5.6.jar
[INFO] Plugin Resolved: maven-clover2-plugin-2.6.3.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: plexus-compiler-api-1.5.3.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: plexus-resources-1.0-alpha-4.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: plexus-utils-1.5.6.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-project-2.0.9.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-plugin-api-2.0.9.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: ant-1.7.1.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-reporting-impl-2.0.4.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-artifact-2.0.9.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: clover-2.6.3.jar
[INFO] Plugin Resolved: maven-install-plugin-2.3.1.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-plugin-api-2.0.6.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-project-2.0.6.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-model-2.0.6.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-artifact-manager-2.0.6.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-artifact-2.0.6.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: plexus-utils-2.0.5.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: plexus-digest-1.0.jar
```

As I undestand **org.apache.commons.logging.Log** from **commons-logging** library and it is needed to exclude that library from some dependency. But I do not see **commons-logging** in my dependency list.

The problem is that I cannot find where should I exclude **commons-logging**.

How can I find where should I exclude **commons-logging** dependency? Or is there any other issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an specific version dependency to your pom like:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I've see sometimes that fix it and sometimes gives you more information about transitive dependency